# How to make one controller's button action go to another view?

Tags: ios

I just completed the ios tutorial, and while I can manipulate a single screen now, I am not sure how to implement a "button listener" and tell that button to go to another view that I tell it to go to.

Here is my code so far:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *homeToLearn;

- (IBAction)homeToPlanBusiness:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)homeToLearn:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)homeToMyPlans:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)homeToSettings:(id)sender;

@end
```

how do I make one of these buttons go to a LeanController that I made? I guess I need to make a LearnView but even once I make that, how do I tie them in together?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do this in code, with storyboards or IB? What version of iOS are you trying to target?

Generally speaking, there are two main ways to accomplish what you want to do. If you want it to be "navigation based" you would do something like this after creating a navigation controller to handle the different view controllers: 
`[self.navController pushViewController:newLeanController animated:YES]`

If you are just swapping views you can do something like: 
`[self.view addSubview:newLeanView]`

Comment: thanks - I think your first example seems like something I am trying to do. I am just trying to show a new view.  But how do I tell the system to do it only on a certain button press and not the other buttons?

Comment: You add a `selector`, i.e. a method, to a button's target action. You would use `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` it would look something like: `[saveButton addTarget:self action:@selector(saveButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];`

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C, IBActions, or even plain old instance methods, are not "listened for", they are wired (literally in Interface Builder) to a button which broadcasts an event when it is touched.  To go to another view, have a look at UINavigationController's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Regardless of iOS, Xcode, or SDK version, any method declared with the IBAction return value (a `typedef` of `void` anyhow), interface builder is alerted that the method is now available to be hooked up to an interface element.  In your case, a button which you drag onto the canvas of your XIB.  At which point, under the connections tab for your class, you drag it's action to the event sender (in this case, the button), and viola, it's all magically set for you when the nib is unarchived.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which iOS tutorial you went through, but most tutorials will introduce you to these concepts. The process of linking buttons to actions and transitioning between view controllers is rich enough that it justifies a whole tutorial of its own (and they're out there, e.g. [Ray Wenderlich](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials); [Stanford](http://itunes.apple.com/us/itunes-u/iphone-application-development/id384233225); [Lynda](http://www.lynda.com/iOS-tutorials/iOS-SDK-Essential-Training/92179-2.html); just google it and you should get tons of hits), and there's no way any of us can do it justice in a simple answer to your question. This is further complicated because the answer depends a lot upon a lot of different questions (are you using ARC? are you using storyboards? etc.).